# Javascript Validation Malfunctioning

Tags: javascript, validation

So, I'm trying to validate a form input which is supposed to throw an error alert if the entered value is greater than the available quota.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function validateform() {
                var num = document.add_form.required_number.value;

                var quota = document.add_form.quota.value;


                if(num>quota) {
                    alert("Required Number Exceeds Demand Quota! The Allowed Quota is " + quota);
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error " + num + " " + quota);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

But unfortunately, even thought the entered value is higher than the quota available it does not go inside the if condition. So I wrote the else to see if the values are correctly assigned to the variables. It was correctly assigned. So after I submit the form I get an alert
[image]

so, this means that it executed the else statement even though the if statement was satisfied..

Comment: Field values are always text, you need to convert them to numbers before comparing with `>` or `<`.

Comment: what is `required_number` in ` var num = document.add_form.required_number.value;`?

Comment: Use ParseInt() function to parse the values then comapre

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj `add_form` is the name of the form, and `required_number` is the name of an input field in the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is due to the fact that all HTML input values are always treated as text, in which case `'5555' > '9'` is false.

It is not even a matter of native JS or jQuery, as proven [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k92dexv7/).

So, to get the correct comparison, you must first convert them to numbers, for example by using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) if you expect an integer, or simply with [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

```js
$(function() {
  console.log('native type = ' + typeof document.getElementById('test').value);
  console.log('jquery type = ' + typeof $('#test').val());
  console.log("'5555' > '9' is " + ('5555' > '9' ? 'true' : 'false'));
  console.log(" 5555  >  9  is " + (5555 > 9 ? 'true' : 'false'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="test" value="123"/>
```